# DNS ATTACK \/ or some kind of an error, i don't know

Tags: linux, security, firewall

I am getting those errors in my CSF firewall, I would like to know how can I stop it.
is it type of an attack?
also if it is, how can I stop it?

```
Mar 11 22:48:57 root named[7598]: client 197.88.45.249#40570: query (cache) 'dhs.gov/ANY/IN' denied
Mar 11 22:48:57 root named[7598]: client 83.105.135.65#11285: query (cache) 'mdynmjkvmdobqhmp.www.333ae.com/A/IN' denied
Mar 11 22:48:57 root named[7598]: client 95.212.1.207#49015: query (cache) 'xpwqiyecjdg.www.333fe.com/A/IN' denied
Mar 11 22:48:57 root named[7598]: client 2.5.21.2#5900: query (cache) 'aopdrfghiwxlz.www.666na.com/A/IN' denied
Mar 11 22:48:57 root named[7598]: client 98.19.246.152#963: query (cache) 'dhs.gov/ANY/IN' denied
Mar 11 22:48:57 root named[7598]: client 92.142.219.147#37553: query (cache) 'czanid.www.444he.com/A/IN' denied
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't stop them. Shit like this is just part and parcel of having something on the internet. You'll see all sorts of brute force SSH attacks, bots probing for PHPMyAdmin logins that they will try to exploit, bots looking for old Wordpress installations or even looking for servers still explioitable by ShellShock or Heartbleed or unpatched Windows servers. The internet is a big, scary place.

If you're not running a public DNS resolver, then just make sure your DNS port is closed on your firewall and be done with it. If you *are* running a DNS resolver, then make sure it's fully patched and up to date and keep an eye out for [CVEs](https://cve.mitre.org/) that effect you.

Comment: I mean, I got both denyhosts and CSF installed ony my server, there is something else i need to do? maybe configure something? also are you sure this logs are certainly an attack?

Comment: Not necessarily an attack, but definitely within the norms of 'stuff that happens on the internet.' Depending on how paranoid you are you can put in firewalls that block know botnets.

Comment: which firewalls? yoshi?